Could it be possible to predict the effects of a universe with universal constants different to ours?
I am attempting to construct a relatively hard-sci-fi world involving a universe that 'evolved' with different universal constants to ours
The more I thought about it, the more I realize it is unable to predict the effects of even relatively simple concepts such as universes with extreme differences in constants to ours
Here is what I have figured out so far now:
With a universe with a strong nuclear force far higher than ours, it becomes feasible for elements at the upper reaches of our own periodic table to be stable for longer, if not outright permanently stable
Far weaker nuclear force? You might not find any atoms past hydrogen or helium
A universe with a far faster speed of light would appear to 'flow faster' time-wise compared to our own since information as a whole can travel far faster
Since I seem to have great difficulty predicting the outcomes of varying universal constants, it is hard to draw out their 'outcomes' without a healthy dose of handwavium
Are there any other constants whose changes cause great changes such as to the point of not allowing anything past the first 3 elements of the periodic table to form, or heavily increasing the energy released in fusion and fission allowing for a human race to take off quite literally with uranium-powered fission reactors, for example?
Edit: To reiterate, I am not involving human life in writing of this supposed alternate universe(s). I am looking to do a relatively hard-sci-fi 'modeling' of what the outcome of such a universe would be. I will not be involving travel to said universe in any form so different constants tearing apart our travels would not apply here
Similar to how we modeled the existence of blackholes and gravastars, even though being in their close presence would obliterate us, I merely want to model what these universes would produce in the form of stellar structures, not outright life. Again, I am not planning on involving any travel to said universe, so the problem here is that of modeling the effects of vastly different constant values

You're asking too many questions on a service that's designed to host one question at a time, so to address your title question: it's really hard if not impossible. The way we experience reality is tied up in those constants, so what you're really asking is, "how would someone in our universe perceive another universe with different constants?" The people from that second universe would perceive their universe as normal. Questions about (e.g.) what would happen if light speed was different have been asked here before, so to avoid being closed as a duplicate, you might want to do some research.

Minus one for complete lack of research. See for example Just Six Numbers: The Deep Forces That Shape The Universe by Martin Rees, and  The Fallacy of Fine Tuning by Victor J. Stenger. (And at least the first of those two books is pretty famous.)

I swear that I've encountered at least a dozen versions of this question, but can't find the duplicate target.

@AlexP I can pretty much guarantee that neither of those books are famous outside of niche communities of physicists. (obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/2501/).  The standard of research for SE is not if a person has read any specific book but if they can find a full, conclusive, and easy to understand answer with a simple internet search. Having plugged his exact question into Google and reviewed the results, I think there is enough ambiguity and conflicting information on the topic to justify the question.

@JBH I hadn't made myself clear in my initial question, apologies. My question wasn't how one would perceive in a universe of different constants, but rather what a universe of different constants would 'be'. No travel to this 'other' universe is involved. Similar to how we modeled a blackhole's existence even though it would tear us apart if we went close, I want to model what such a universe would 'evolve' to be (not in the sense of lifeforms, but in the sense of stellar structures)

@Hash Except that it is how one would peceive the univese of different constants. You suggest yourself that a faster speed of light might indicate time flows differently. From the perspective of someone in-universe, time would flow "normally." The perception is yours and the difference is in comparision with Real Life. However, based on your comment... you're asking for a LOT. Can you narrow the question?

A notable hard-SF  already written is "Dragon's Egg" by Robert L Forward. In our universe, but the aliens are living on the surface of a neutron star, living about a million times faster than we do.

The Fine-Tuning Argument
The constants in our universe must be precisely what they are in order for anything resembling a universe to not rapidly collapse into a giant black hole, cause violent runaway fusion, or completely fail to form stars and matter.  According to the fine-tuning argument, even minor changes in any one of 6 to 26 universal constants would make a long lasting universe impossible.  The balance of these constants are so precise that most astrophysicists agree that the likelihood of our universal constants being random is somewhere between about 1:1e40 and 1:1e100.
So, if you assume a multiverse in which another universe has noticably different constants than our own, it will almost certainly be a barren starless expanse unless it is much much younger than our own universe in which case the likelihood of surviving inside of a young proto universe to be able to make any observations is for all practical purposes 0%.
That said, it is conceivable that you could survive traveling to a failed universe where the laws are noticably different since most of the Fine Tuning Argument limitations are based on cosmological masses and time scales; so, even though a 2% change in the strong nuclear force would cause all the hydrogen in the early universe to fuse into helium within the first few minutes of existence... that does not automatically mean that the cool, low density hydrogen in your body/spaceship would behave noticably different.

+1 because I believe the physics you're explaining... but let's throw the [tag:science-based] tag out the window and assume the OP wants a multiverse story. Do you think it's possible to describe a rational perceived difference between the two universes that can be rationalized by dinking around with the constants? How would a worldbuilder construct a fantasy universe using the constants as their MacGuffins?

There are far fewer than 26 fundamental constants; most universal constants are interrelated. See for example Martin Rees, Just Six Numbers: The Deep Forces That Shape The Universe. Out of those, the gravitational constant G is not related to anything else and at least it can be changed freely plus or minus quite a few percent without any massive side effects. P.S. The opinion that the fundamental constants must be exactly what they are is controversial; see for example  Victor J. Stenger, The Fallacy of Fine Tuning.

@JBH Adjacency: If you assume a universe with similar constants will be "closer" in the multiverse than one that is wildly different, then traveling to Earth like fantasy worlds would be both easy and probable, as opposed to the far more numerous but distant dead universes, but the OP is asking for significantly different constants.

@AlexP Yes there are a very wide range of estimates in the Fine Tuning Argument which is why I left such a large margin of error, but even Martin Rees who wrote that book says that the odds of the universe being able to sustain life are about 1 in 1e60.

The "odds" depend fundamentally (see what I did here) on the presumed allowable range for the fundamental constants. If we take the allowable ranges to be any real value greater than zero then quite obviously the odds are zero. If we take the allowable ranges to be finite intervals then we can make the odds as large as we want.

Theoretically, aren't other stable configurations of constants possible?

@AlexP My claim was "most astrophysicists agree that the likelihood of our universal constants being random is somewhere between about 1:1e40 and 1:1e100", I'm not saying that it must be true, just that it is the current view of the scientific majority.  That said, the OP has made claims about his setting that are consistent with the Multiversal Solution to the Fine Tuning Argument.  So, if you take his declarations as givens (Which we do because this is WB.SE), then you would have enough data to establish standard distributions and prove the theory correct.

@DDriggs00 The vast majority of solutions result in the universe rapidly collapsing into a blackhole, stars and planets not being able to accrete, or stars that explosive blow up or collapse as soon as they form... So, maybe there are a few bands of alternative kinds of realities that work, but throwing a couple of extra needles in a haystack the size of the observable universe does not making finding a needle somewhere in it easier in any meaningful way.

Thank you for your answer! Though I don't want to involve travelling to these exotic universes, I do want to write about what said supposed universes would be like. Similar to how we modeled the existence of black holes before actually finding one. I did not word that clearly in my initial question
So for all instances and purposes, it is either life like our own, exotic life, or the usual possibility of being a being a barren starless/blackhole-ful univese with tiny changes to constants?

@Hash Yes, unless you change things by very tiny amounts that would require fine instruments to even notice, it will all be barren starless or blackhole-full universes.

@Hash and to underscore a necessary truth: We have one and only one data point when it comes to life in any universe: Earth. So when you say "exotic," that's meaningless, because we have no evidence (at all) of what "exotic" means. For all we know, life as we see it on Earth may be the only expression of life in this and any universe. There's no equation that can prove the statement true or false.

@JBH Multiverse theory exists because without it quantum physics would violate causality.  The OP's setting already supports multiverses; so, it would seem counterintuitive for him to adopt the purely speculative parts of multiverse theory without adopting the parts that actually have some basis for being.  This means his multiverse should contain the outcome of every possible quantum outcome in addition to every possible set of universal constants.

If this is the case, then there should be countless universes that are imperceptibly different from our own and an insanely larger number of universes between those and the ones where no life exists.  So, while I am saying that there are insanely larger number of universes that are barren wastelands, I am not saying that there are by any means a small number of universes where life should exist.

@Nosajimiki The idea of a multiverse predates quantum physics by a fair amount of time. Worse, the multiverse hyposthesis is just mathematics. Math is a tool of science, but it isn't science, which demands repeatable empirical observations and experimentation. There is, at this time, one and only one data point: Earth. Anything and everything else has more in common with Hollywood than science.

@JHB yes, the idea of a multiverse predates quantum physics in principle, but it would solve several possible problems in science (including the causality issue of quantum physics) even if we can not experimentally prove its existence at this time. Some scientific discoveries, like black holes for example, only existed as mathematical possibilities long before we could prove that they were real.
